# ¿Por qué no puedo guardar datos en la base de datos MySQL que contengan comillas simples?

Tags: mysql

Intento guardar datos que contengan comillas simples pero bota este error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1065886910', '1065886949')' at line 12 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mirenacer\modelo\ValidarDatosMedico.php:433 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mirenacer\modelo\ValidarDatosMedico.php(433): PDO->query('INSERT INTO his...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mirenacer\controlador\control.php(161): ValidarDatosM->InsertarHistoriaM() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mirenacer\modelo\ValidarDatosMedico.php on line 433

con este  código hago la inserción:

```
public function InsertarHistoriaM(){//inserta un nueva historia psi

                                  $sql="INSERT INTO historia_clinica_general


                                      VALUES('$this->hcg_id',
                                             '$this->hcg_fecha',

                                              '$this->hcg_motivo_consulta',
                                              '$this->hcg_enfermedad_actual',
                                              '$this->hcg_revision_sistemas',
                                              '$this->hcg_examen_fisico',
                                              '$this->hcg_diagnostico',
                                              '$this->hcg_plan',
                                              '$this->paci_doc',
                                             '$this->empl_doc')";

                                  $insert=$this->db->query($sql);

}
```

código del controlador:

```
case 5:

require_once("../modelo/ValidarDatosMedico.php");//para editar pacientes despues de listados


$datohistoriaM=new ValidarDatosM();

$datohistoriaM->setHcg_id($_REQUEST['hcg_id']);
$datohistoriaM->setHcg_fecha($_REQUEST['hcg_fecha']);
$datohistoriaM->setHcg_motivo_consulta($_REQUEST['hcg_motivo_consulta']);
$datohistoriaM->setHcg_enfermedad_actual($_REQUEST['hcg_enfermedad_actual']);
$datohistoriaM->setHcg_revision_sistemas($_REQUEST['hcg_revision_sistemas']);
$datohistoriaM->setHcg_examen_fisico($_REQUEST['hcg_examen_fisico']);
$datohistoriaM->setHcg_diagnostico($_REQUEST['hcg_diagnostico']);
$datohistoriaM->setHcg_plan($_REQUEST['hcg_plan']);
$datohistoriaM->setPaci_doc($_REQUEST['paci_doc']);
$datohistoriaM->setEmpl_doc($_REQUEST['empl_doc']);

$datohistoriaM->InsertarHistoriaM();


require_once("../vista/medico/vista_medico.php");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('Datos Guardados Correctamente');</script>
<?php

break;
```

código de ¿modificación:

```
public function ModificarHistoriaM(){

                                          $sql="UPDATE historia_clinica_general

                                                SET 

                                                 hcg_id='$this->hcg_id',
                                                 hcg_fecha='$this->hcg_fecha',
                                                 hcg_motivo_consulta='$this->hcg_motivo_consulta',
                                                 hcg_enfermedad_actual='$this->hcg_enfermedad_actual',
                                                 hcg_revision_sistemas='$this->hcg_revision_sistemas',
                                                 hcg_examen_fisico='$this->hcg_examen_fisico',
                                                 hcg_diagnostico='$this->hcg_diagnostico',
                                                 hcg_plan='$this->hcg_plan',
                                                 paci_doc='$this->paci_doc',
                                                 empl_doc='$this->empl_doc'

                                                WHERE 
                                                 hcg_id='$this->hcg_id'";


                                           $update=$this->db->query($sql);

                                            return true;



}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la sentencia completa que produce este error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Aclaración**

Luego de la edición de la pregunta, queda más claro lo que está pasando. Dejo la respuesta original [abajo] porque creo que es de utilidad.

**Respuesta**

De la manera que está escrita tu consulta, estás concatenando datos, probablemente ingresados por el usuario directamente en tu sentencia SQL y con ello corriendo riesgo de fallos, pero más grave aún el riesgo de ataques de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

En este caso particular, alguno de los campos que estás incluyendo dentro del `insert` trae una comilla simple `'` y esto está provocando que la sentencia completa falle.

Mi recomendación principal para corregir esta situación es cambiar tu código para el uso de [queries parametrizados](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php), pasando los valores utilizando [bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php), algo como:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO historia_clinica_general
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->hcg_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $this->hcg_fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
//otros campos...
$stmt->bindParam(10, $this->empl_doc, PDO::PARAM_STR, 200);

$insert = $stmt->execute();
```

**Respuesta original**

SQL en general, y MySQL en particular, permiten la inserción de comillas simples utilizando la convención siguiente<sup>1</sup>:

Las cadenas se encierran entre comillas simples, por ejemplo:

```
update Tabla
   set MiCampo = 'dato'
 where id = 1;
```

Si una cadena contiene una comilla simple, entonces, esta se *sustituye* por dos comillas simples, dentro de la cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```sql
update Tabla
   set MiCampo = 'data''s'
 where id = 1;
```

Almacena el valor `data's` en el campo.

De esto se deriva que, si esta comilla simple se encuentre al inicio o al final de la cadena, se utiliza una *triple comilla*, (dos que representan la comilla que va dentro de la cadena y otra que la inicia o termina.

Por ejemplo:

```sql
 update Tabla
   set MiCampo = '''dato'''
 where id = 1;
```

Almacena el valor `'dato'` en el campo.

Finalmente, una cadena que tiene una sola comilla luce de esta forma:

```sql
 update Tabla
   set MiCampo = ''''
 where id = 1;
```

Esto almacena el valor `'` en el campo.

---

**<sup>1</sup>** Conozco esta convención también en pascal y la atribuyo a este, no sé si viene de algún otro lenguaje que también usara comilla simple como delimitador de las cadenas o fue inventada en este lenguaje.

Comment: Hola jachguate, como podra aplicr lo que me dices en esta linea  '$this->hcg_motivo_consulta', acabe de editar la pregunta para que veas la consulta que se hace.

Comment: Listo, edité también la respuesta.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mirenacer\modelo\ValidarDatosMedico.php:433 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mirenacer\controlador\control.php(161): ValidarDatosM->InsertarHistoriaM() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mirenacer\modelo\ValidarDatosMedico.php on line 433

Comment: Hola,con cualquiera de la sentencias me sale ese error, pero se me olvido decir que esa insercioon pasa por un controlador , voy a colocar el codigo para que me aconsejes que puedo modificar en el controlador.

Comment: Si utilizas `PDO`, la sintaxis es ligeramente diferente, hay que adaptar la respuesta. Asumí que utilizabas `mysqli`.

Comment: Listo, ya está adaptada de nuevo. Para futuras ocasiones, te sugiero incluir toda esta información en la pregunta desde el inicio. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado,estaba sobrando una     , ) ;  si quieres corrigelo, igual lo modifique y funciono.

Comment: Como podría aplicar esto mismo pero en un UPDATE,necesito modificar las mismas variables pero presenta el mismo error.Anexo el código con el que estoy modificando.

Comment: Creo que ya tienes suficiente información y vínculos a la documentación para poder hacer esta adaptación por ti mismo. La idea del sitio no es encontrar quién haga tu tarea/trabajo, sino una guía y una fuente de aprendizaje para que lo hagas por ti mismo. Un saludo. ;)

Answer (score 0):

'1065886910', '1065886949')'

Pudieras mostrar la consulta completa, por que lo que alcanzo a ver en esta parte, tu estas metiendo valores en comillas simples, pero al final del paréntesis veo otra comilla simple, esta ultima podría ser la causante del error

Entonces, pudieras mostrar la consulta completa